# java 8, CompletableFuture

Tags: java, java-8

In the below code snippet, can anyone let me know what happens when we invoke CompletableFuture.supplyAsync() and when a value is returned will it be returned in a separate thread?

```
// Run a task specified by a Supplier object asynchronously
CompletableFuture<String> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(new Supplier<String>() {
    @Override
    public String get() {
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
        return "Result of the asynchronous computation";
    }
});

// Block and get the result of the Future
String result = future.get();
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: supplied operation is non-blocking and the result will be returned when it's available

Answer (score 1):

This returns a new **Completable Future** object which basically get
executed in a new **thread** borrowed from **ForkJoinPool**. Please refer to javadoc -

```
/**
 * Returns a new CompletableFuture that is asynchronously completed
 * by a task running in the {@link ForkJoinPool#commonPool()} with
 * the value obtained by calling the given Supplier.
 *
 * @param supplier a function returning the value to be used
 * to complete the returned CompletableFuture
 * @param <U> the function's return type
 * @return the new CompletableFuture
 */
public static <U> CompletableFuture<U> supplyAsync(Supplier<U> supplier) {
    return asyncSupplyStage(asyncPool, supplier);
}
```